# unexpected output in c++ program

Tags: c++

I'm working on a workshop and I've pretty much completed it but I'm having trouble with debugging.

The program compiles and runs but I'm having an issue where after the user is asked to input the data and is sent to the display function, it displays junk.

I've ran the program through debug mode and I've come to the conclusion that the inputs are not getting passed to my setter function, but In the code my prof wrote (he wrote the main and asked us to fill some stuff in like memory allocation) it doesn't ask for me to initialize the setter function in the main, am I missing something?

The 'Weather.h' file is where the set aswell as display functions are located in the Weather class.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Weather.h"
using namespace std;
using namespace sict;
int main(){
  int n; //the count of days worth of weather
  // initialize the weather pointer here
  Weather* weather;

  cout << "Weather Data\n";
  cout << "=====================" << endl;
  cout << "Days of Weather: ";
  cin >> n;
  cin.ignore();
  // allocate dynamic memory here
  weather = new Weather[n];

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    char date_description[7];
    double high = 0.0, low = 0.0;

    // ... add code to accept user input for
    //weather
    cout << "Enter date: ";
    cin >> date_description;
    cout << "Enter high: ";
    cin >> high;
    cout << "Enter low: ";
    cin >> low;
  }
  cout << endl;
  cout << "Weather report:\n";
  cout << "======================" << endl;

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    weather[i].display();
  }

  // deallocate dynamic memory here
  delete[] weather;
  weather = (Weather*)0;

  return 0;

}
/*
Output Example :
Weather Data
== == == == == == == == == == =
Days of Weather : 3
Enter date : Oct / 1
Enter high : 15
Enter low : 10
Enter date : Nov / 13
Enter high : 10
Enter low : 1.1
Enter date : Dec / 15
Enter high : 5.5
Enter low : -6.5

Weather report :
== == == == == == == == == == ==
Oct / 1_______15.0__10.0
Nov / 13______10.0___1.1
Dec / 15_______5.5__ - 6.5
*/
```

the definition for the set function(In weather):

```
void Weather::set(const char* Date, double high, double low){
        strcpy(date, Date);
        tempHigh = high;
        tempLow = low;
    }
```

Comment: Did you write the code under `// ... add code to accept user input for weather`?

Comment: What setter function?  You read in values for the weather but don't store them anywhere.

Comment: Why do you call `cin.ignore()`? Why not use `std::vector<Weather>`?

Comment: I did write the code under "// ... add code to accept user input for weather", thats the thing! I dont see how the setter will get any of the info there was nothing in the instructions on where to include it or in the file itself, Its pretty much a useless function im not sure how to pass info to it, and the prof wrote it he said so it'll ignore the enter key

Comment: If you know you are reading up to the end of a line and know the enter key (end of line marker) is going to be there, call std::getline. At present you don't really know what you are ignoring, and that's laziness that will lead to trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You read the data and just drop them in the for loop after `weather = new Weather[n];`.
You will have to store them to `weather`. It should be able to be done by this:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    const int store_length = 7;
    char date_description[16];
    char date_description_to_store[store_length];
    int store_pos = 0;
    double high = 0.0, low = 0.0;

    // ... add code to accept user input for
    //weather
    cout << "Enter date: ";
    cin.getline(date_description, sizeof(date_description) / sizeof(date_description[0]));
    for (int i = 0; date_description[i] != '\0' && store_pos < store_length - 1; i++){
      if (date_description[i] != ' ') date_description_to_store[store_pos++] = date_description[i];
    }
    date_description_to_store[store_pos] = '\0';
    cout << "Enter high: ";
    cin >> high;
    cout << "Enter low: ";
    cin >> low;
    weather[i].set(date_description_to_store, high, low); // add this line
    cin.ignore(); // add this line to ignore the new line
  }
```

**UPDATE:** You should use `cin.getline` to read string containing spaces such as `Oct / 1`.
**UPDATE 2:** the buffer of 7 characters is insufficient to read `Oct / 1`. You will have to allocate more memomry or use `std::string`.
**UPDATE 3**: You have to convert the input format like `Oct / 3` to storing format like `Jan/21`. Note that there are no error checking in this code.

Comment: I'm not sure how to put code in a comment so I'll add the weather function above in the question

Comment: In the instructions it says "A 6-characters long C-style string (7 chars, including the NULL)," I am including string in the cpp if thats what you mean?

Comment: UPDATE: so it now works! thank you very much! https://gyazo.com/2565dd882f344497839763609354820d << screen shot of it! I really appreciate your help mikeCat!

Comment: That may be the proper way to handle this situation but with the workshop's I need to do it exactly as instructed or the system wont accept my submission, its very picky on the output right down to white space.